# Что означает оператор стрелка -> в Kotlin? Эквивалент в Java

Tags: java, kotlin

Всем привет! Подскажите плиз! Пытаюсь разобрать один паттерн, пример использования Android Architecture Components, написанный на Koltin'e и столкнулся с синтаксисом, который не могу понять.

Что в данном синтаксисе означает эта "стрелка" -> ? 
Как этот код будет выглядеть в Java?  Спасибо огромное

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()

    firebaseDatabaseLiveData.observe(this, Observer { articles -> adapter.setArticles(articles)
        }
    })
}
```

Как этот код будет выглядеть в Java?

```
@Override 
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();    
        firebaseDatabaseLiveData.observe(this, //... а вот дальше непонятно

        });
    }
```

Comment: Точно также. Почитайте про лямбды.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В Java на этом месте может быть как [лямбда-выражение](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

```
firebaseDatabaseLiveData.observe(this, articles -> adapter.setArticles(articles));
```

так и [ссылка на метод](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

```
firebaseDatabaseLiveData.observe(this, adapter::setArticles);
```